# Обработка компонентов Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

У меня есть несколько кастомных компонентов. Предположим 3 радиокнопки `<RadioButton>`: пол, год, имя

```
<RadioButton name="gender" title="пол" :items='{"женский","мужской"}'></RadioButton>
<RadioButton name="name" title="имя" :items='{"Олег","Кирилл","Андрей","Светлана","Ольга"}'></RadioButton>
<RadioButton name="year" title="год" :items='{2000,2001,2002,2003,2004}'></RadioButton>
```

Как влиять на другие кнопки при нажатии какой нибудь из них
при выборе пола у меня высвечивались (добавлялись например на них классы) радиокнопки с соответствующими именами, при нажатии на имя были доступны некоторые кнопки с годами (какому то имени соответствуют года, например Кирилл - 2000, 2001, 2002; а Олег - 2003, 2004, 2005)

В конце я нажимаю на кнопку `<SubmitButton>` и мне выдает массив данных со значениями со всех кнопок

```
{
gender: "male",
name: "Кирилл",
year: 2000
}
```